# No suitable driver found for jdbc:hive2

Tags: hadoop, jdbc, hive

Trying to connect to hive using JDBC.

Url: `jdbc:hive2://...`

Driver: `org.apache.hive.jdbc.HiveDriver`

I have on the classpath:

- `/usr/hdp/current/hive-client/lib/hive-jdbc.jar` (3.1.0)
- `/usr/hdp/current/hive-client/lib/hive-common.jar` (3.1.0)
- `/usr/hdp/current/hive-client/lib/hive-service.jar` (3.1.0)
- `/usr/hdp/current/hadoop-client/hadoop-common.jar` (3.1.1)
- `/usr/hdp/current/hive-client/lib/hive-service.jar` (3.1.0)
- `/usr/hdp/current/hive-client/lib/libthrift-0.9.3-1.jar`
- `/usr/hdp/current/hive-client/lib/libfb303-0.9.3.jar`
- `/usr/hdp/current/hive-client/lib/hive-exec.jar` (3.1.0)
- `/usr/hdp/current/hive-client/lib/hive-jdbc-handler.jar` (3.1.0)

And I get an error "No suitable driver found for jdbc:hive2". What am I doing wrong?

Apache Hive (version 3.1.0.3.1.4.0-315)

```
  def configure(hiveConfig: HiveSettings): Either[String, Unit] =
for {
  _ <- Either
    .catchNonFatal(Class.forName("org.apache.hive.jdbc.HiveDriver"))
    .leftMap(_.getMessage)
  _ <- Either.right(ConnectionPool.singleton(hiveConfig.url, null, null))
} yield {
  Logger.debug(s"Hive URL: [${hiveConfig.url}]")
}
```

Comment: If you get the exact error _"No suitable driver found for jdbc:hive2"_, then your URL is only `jdbc:hive2` and hence invalid.

Answer (score 0):

Try loading the Hive Driver explicitly before opening up the connection. It seems like your version is not JDBC4 compliant, i.e. will not get loaded automatically.

```
try {
      Class.forName("org.apache.hive.jdbc.HiveDriver");
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```